# How to prevent minimized app to stay on foreground after the VoIP call ended?

Tags: android, android-activity, voip

I'm trying to develop a VoIP call application on Android and there is a problem which I cannot find any solution. Also, I don't know how to search the problem, so let me explain the scenario:
User sends the app to background by pressing the home button (minimize the app). Then when he/she gets a call, my call screen activity comes up. It is ok till here. My problem is the last activity comes to foreground when the call ends, but as the user sent the app to background before the call received he/she wants the app to stay in background after the call ended.
How can I make the application stay in the background after the call ends?

Comment: have a look at moveTaskToBack https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `finish()` when your application's `Activity` ends, start the HOME screen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```